# z-index fighting with position: fixed in a circular fashion

Tags: css

[image]

I have a top div that has `position: fixed`. After the div, I have a menu div also having `position: fixed`, it will be positioned to overlap the top div so it will need a correct z-index. After those divs, I have a div containing the webpage contents with `position: absolute`. It will have a top margin so it will not be overlapped by the top div.

[image]

The menu div has children that are dropdown-menus with `position: absolute`. They should overlap the webpage contents. There is a facebook popup that is a child to the top div, it should overlap everything when it shows.

There is some circularity to this. If the top div is topmost in z-index, the facebook div will overlap everything when it shows. However, the top div will also overlap the menu so it will not show at all.

So how do I fix that?

http://jsfiddle.net/t8sgezz8/

html:

```
<div class="top">
    <div class="facebook">
        <div class="btn"></div>
        <div class="facebook-popup">facebook</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="menu-parent">
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>foo</li>
            <li>bar</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>
                abc
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>abc 1</li>
                    <li>abc 2</li>
                    <li>abc 3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>def</li>
            <li>ghi</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="contents">
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

css:

```
body
{
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0;
}

.top,
.menu-parent,
.facebook
{
  position: fixed;
}

.top
{
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #413d25;
}

.facebook
{    
    top: 20px;
    left: 220px;
}

.menu-parent
{
    top: 30px;
    z-index: 10;
    right: 32px;
}

.btn
{
    background: #4460ae;
    width: 30px;
    height: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.facebook-popup
{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: #ccc;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.menu
{
    color: #fff;
}

.menu > ul
{
    list-style: none;
}

.menu li
{
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

ul.dropdown-menu
{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #879300;
    width: 100px;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 2px;
}

ul.dropdown-menu li
{
    margin-left: 0;
}

.contents
{
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 75px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: you could solve this by making facebook popup and the menu siblings to each other, having a `position:fixed` parent.

Comment: That is true, however, I do not have that option, thanks anyway!

Comment: Hm, maybe I could run a script that moves the facebook like button to a better parent.

Comment: since you've not mentioned all of the limitations that you're facing, it is hard to provide a definite solution. But you'll have to move your elements around to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body
{
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0;
}

.top,
.menu-parent,
.facebook
{
  position: fixed;
}

.top
{
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #413d25;
}

.facebook
{    
    top: 20px;
    left: 220px;
}

.menu-parent
{
    top: 30px;
    z-index: 10;
    right: 32px;
}

.btn
{
    background: #4460ae;
    width: 30px;
    height: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.facebook-popup
{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: #ccc;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:11
}

.menu
{
    color: #fff;
}

.menu > ul
{
    list-style: none;
}

.menu li
{
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

ul.dropdown-menu
{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #879300;
    width: 100px;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 2px;
}

ul.dropdown-menu li
{
    margin-left: 0;
}

.contents
{
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 75px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
    <div class="facebook">
        <div class="btn"></div>
        <div class="facebook-popup">facebook</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="menu-parent">
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>foo</li>
            <li>bar</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>
                abc
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>abc 1</li>
                    <li>abc 2</li>
                    <li>abc 3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>def</li>
            <li>ghi</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="contents">
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Comment: The facebook popup does not overlap the webpage contents nor the menu.